# tup1 = (1, true, 9.6, 5-9k) is showing an error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
tup1 = (1, true, 9.6, 5-9k)

 File "C:\Users\ROHITT~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14504/267088091.py", line 1
    tup1 = (1, true, 9.6, 5-9k)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with `tup1 = (1, true, 9.6, 5-9k)` :

`name 'true' is not defined`

Booleans represent one of two values: `True` or `False`, so `true` must start with a capital T. Replace `true` in `tup1 = (1, true, 9.6, 5-9k)` with `True`.

---

```
tup1 = (1, true, 9.6, 5-9k)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The `k` in `5-9k`  is causing this syntax error. Either `5-9` or `5-9000` would be OK.